# Error in my Shell Script (at kill command)

Tags: shell, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
ssh user@hostname "ps -ef | grep java | grep dev | kill -9 `awk '{print \$2}'` && nohup java -jar application.jar --server.port=8090&"
```

Error:

```
Usage: kill [-lL] [-n signum] [-s signame] job ...
   Or: kill [ options ] -l [arg ...]
```

Does anyone know what is causing the error?

Comment: check each command manually, are you sure ps -ef|grep java|grep dev is returning a line?

Comment: also, remove the '\', that's a syntax error:
awk '{print $2}' should work

Answer (score 0):

The \ in awk print is a syntax error.

Try this:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep dev | kill -9 `awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: This command works in Server. But when I put the same command in Jenkins Job (Execute Shell), it is prompting the error.

Comment: `Error: Usage: kill [-lL] [-n signum] [-s signame] job ...
   Or: kill [ options ] -l [arg ...]`

Comment: Jenkins may be running the command as a different user and it may not be getting the output of the previous commands (before the kill pipe), check if that's the case